# Google Checkout Polling API - How do I set my SSL certificate path/use polling without an SSL?

Tags: php, google-checkout, android-pay

I downloaded the php sample code for Google Checkout, (from https://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-php-sample-code/downloads/list) and am attempting to get pollingdemo.php to work.

My issue is the following:

```
$merchant_id = "XXXXXXXX";
$merchant_key = "XXXXXXXXX";
$environment = "sandbox";
$certificate_path = "?????????"; // set your SSL CA cert path
```

I do not know what to enter for the certificate path. I do own an SSL certificate and it is enabled for my site. I called my hosting provider, and they did not know what I should enter there either.

Alternatively, I would like to implement Polling without an SSL, which should be possible according to [this](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Features). However, I do not know how to do this with pollingdemo.php.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of ContinueTokenRequest in googlepoll.php lets you instanciate it without providing a certificate at all:

```
function ContinueTokenRequest($id, $key, $env, $cp = null) { ...
```

Did you try the code with removed certificate value?

```
$tokenRequest = new ContinueTokenRequest($merchant_id, $merchant_key, $environment);
```

Comment: I had tried this, but hadn't realized there was a second issue - the start time of the continue token was too long ago. Thanks!